# Does calling a scalar function in a select statement multiple times run the function multiple times, and how to get around that if so

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I have a select statement with a scalar function in it used in various calculations, does that scalar function get called multiple times? If it does, is there a way to optimize this so it only calls the funciton once per select, as in my real query it will be called thousands of times, X 6 times per select.

For example:

```
SELECT 
[dbo].[fn_Days](@Account) + u.[DayRate],
[dbo].[fn_Days](@Account) / u.[WorkDays]
FROM [dbo].[tblUnit] u
```

All fn_days does is return an int of days worked.

Comment: Right I realize that it runs for every row, but since it is ran 2 times within the same row, could I somehow use that same value so I dont have to run it multiple times per row?

Comment: Noticed that right as you posted your comment.  It could, in theory, store the value, but I doubt it does.  A crude way to figure it out could be to make a function that purposely takes a long time to run and then call it once a query and twice in a query and compare run times.

Comment: See what the query plan is if joining on a set that already has the result of the function as a column.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes the scalar gets called multiple times the way that you have coded it.  One way to make it work would be to wrap it into a subquery like this:

```
SELECT t.[days] + t.[DayRate],
       t.[days] / t.[WorkDays]
FROM (
     SELECT 
     [dbo].[fn_Days](@Account) as days,
     u.[DayRate],
     u.[WorkDays]
     FROM [dbo].[tblUnit] u) as t
```

This way fn_Days only gets called once per row, rather than twice, or six times like you mentioned.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Functions are deterministic which means that it will always return the same value for a given parameter. You are using a variable as the parameter so you can call the function once before executing the query and use the result in the query instead of calling the function.

```
DECLARE @Days int
SET @Days = [dbo].[fn_Days](@Account)

SELECT 
  @Days + u.[DayRate],
  @Days / u.[WorkDays]
FROM [dbo].[tblUnit] u
```